# Хранимые процедуры и Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Нужен совет от умных людей.
Встала задача переделать проект с чистого Django на Django Rest Framework + Vue js, база Postgres, все манипуляции с данными происходят через хранимые процедуры (просмотр, добавление, удаление, редактирование).
Вопрос в чем, DRF использует сериализаторы для представления данных в готовом JSON виде, но сериализаторы работают с моделями и коробочной orm, как быть с хранимыми процедурами? Можно ли обойти сериализаторы, если база возвращает уже нужный формат данных и как в DRF вообще происходит работа с хранимыми процедурами?

Comment: Можете добавить код, которым вы достаёте данные из БД,  сериализированные данные и желаемый результат?